# c++ initialize class member variable depends on other member variable

Tags: c++, arrays, class-constructors, in-class-initialization

Basically, a non-static member `theta` which initialize by another class member but well initialized. Then `valley_max` initialized by `theta` as you can see. Right now everything works fine. Then I want to initialize a array whose bound is `valley_max`. First, the I got error :

> invalid use of non-static data member

Then I add `static const int valley_max` as you can see. But I got error like:

> array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token

I just wondering if I can initialize the array whose bound initialized by a member variable which initialized by another member variables.
Thanks for your help.

**AP_Tmxk_VFH.cpp**

```
AP_Tmxk_VFH::AP_Tmxk_VFH() :
    l(5),
    threshold(5),
    safe_space(0.7),
    detected_range(2.5),
    theta(degrees(acos(1-sq(safe_space)/(2*sq(detected_range))))),
    valley_max(round_float(180.0/theta)),
    valley_count(0),
{
}
```

**AP_Tmxk_VFH.h**

```
class AP_Tmxk_VFH {
privte:
       int l;
       int threshold;
       int safe_space;
       int theta;
       int detected_range;
       static const int valley_max ;
       struct{

         bool inside_valley  = false;
         uint16_t up_bound   = 0;  
         uint16_t down_bound = 0; 
   }valley[valley_max];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your specific issue is due to the fact that variable length arrays are not supported in C++. Consider using a `std::vector` or another C++ standard library container instead.

**But you have further problems** (which in my opinion makes your question interesting): the order of member initialisation is the order they appear in the class definition, **not** the order they appear in the initialisation.

For example, in your case `theta` is initialised *before* `detected_range`, and since the latter is not initialised at the point you use it in the evaluation of `theta`, **the behaviour of your code is undefined!**

In your case, unless you need the members to be `const`, I'd initialise the ones that are not set to literals in the constructor body if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

> I just wondering if I can initialize the array whose bound initialized by a member variable which initialized by another member variables.

No, you can not.

You can not, because such variable is

> not an integer constant

like the error message says. The value of the member variable is unknown at compile time - which contradicts with the requirement that the size of an array must be compile time constant (i.e. known at compile time).

Solution: Use a `std::vector` instead. The size of a vector is not locked at compile time.